# How can I make the video work properly with visual also?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

For some time I've made an app and I have a very weird problem. I have two activities. One is named Speech and one is named Yoga. In both of them I have multiple videos with web url. The videos in Speech work perfectly. But in Yoga, when the video starts, the screen remains black, and only the audio works and the MediaController. I noticed this happenes only on some phone resolutions (Ex: for samsung A50 the video works normal, but for samsung j3 it doesn't.) I thought the problem is caused because of the video specs so I am going to show you the specs of the videos:

Speech video(the video that works:
Lenght: 1:21
Frame width:1080
Frame height:1860
Data rate:584kbts
Size:7.53 MB

Yoga video(the video that doesn't work:
Lenght: 8:15
Frame width:1080
Frame height:2260
Data rate:720kbts
Size:42 MB

The code is the same for both:

```
 VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.speech);
    videoView.setVideoPath("my_url");

    MediaController mc = new MyMediaController(videoView.getContext());
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> onBackPressed());
```

Layout:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/s"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gridLayout7">

</VideoView>
```

The videos were made in the same way also.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Screen resolution won't affect playback. My guess is that issue appears because phones have different supported video codes. Check which codec is used in your yoga videos (via VLC player or ffplay). Then convert those to widely supported codec (like H264)

Comment: Also, there you can check which codecs are supported on which android versions: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#video-formats

Comment: Alternatively, you can use ffmpeg to play videos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226484/use-ffmpeg-in-android-for-playing-video

Comment: Thank you for the suggetions, but the videos were made in the same way and have almost the same details. But I will try.

Comment: Why don't you use `ExoPlayer` rather than `VideoView`?

Comment: I just didn't try it yet. I only wanted to use something less complicated at first